# Anchor tag syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an error in this line:

```
jQuery('a[href$=jpg], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=.mov] , a[href$=.swf] , a[href*=vimeo.com] , a[href*=youtube.com]').each(function()
```

Please specify the mistake in the above line.

This is my code:

```
if(autolink)
    {
        jQuery('a[href$=jpg], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=.mov] , a[href$=.swf] , a[href*=vimeo.com] , a[href*=youtube.com]').each(function()
        {
            if(!jQuery(this).attr('rel') != undefined && !jQuery(this).attr('rel') != '' && !jQuery(this).hasClass('noLightbox'))
            {
                jQuery(this).attr('rel','lightbox[auto_group]')
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't like the periods in expressions used that way.  Put quotes around attribute values, as in:

```
a[href$=".mov"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G9EZR/

Answer (score 0):

try adding quotes to selectors, like:

```
jQuery('a[href$=jpg], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=.mov] , a[href$=.swf] , a[href*=vimeo.com] , a[href*=youtube.com]').each(function()
```

to

```
jQuery('a[href$="jpg"], a[href$="png"], a[href$="gif"], a[href$="jpeg"], a[href$=".mov"] , a[href$=".swf"] , a[href*="vimeo.com"] , a[href*="youtube.com"]').each(function()
```